# Orchard cms Custom choice list field with url Alternate

Tags: orchardcms, alternate

I am using `Choice List Field` from orchard gallery. So far so good..

Next I did a few changes in the code 
`Modules.Contrib.ChoiceList.views.EditorTemplate.Flieds.Contrib.ChoiceList.cshtml`.
The objective was to put a table around radio button and it is working – no problem.

With the following code:

```
    @model Contrib.ChoiceList.ViewModels.ChoiceListFieldViewModel
    @using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
    @{ var i = 0; }


    <fieldset class="FieldSoubedenos">
    <legend>@Model.Name</legend>
    <table class="data-table-Soubedenos">
        <tbody>
        <tr >    
            @if( Model.ListMode == "radio" )
            {
                foreach (var option in Model.Options.Split(';'))
                {

                    if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(option) )
                    {

                        <td>
                            <label>@Html.RadioButton("SelectedValue", "",     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.SelectedValue))<i>unset</i></label>
                        </td>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>
                            <label>@Html.RadioButton("SelectedValue", option, (option == Model.SelectedValue))@option</label>
                        </td>
                    }  

                    ++i;
                        if (i % 2 == 0)
                        {  

                         @:</tr><tr>                                            
                        }               
                }         
            }


    else
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.Options.Split(';'), Model.SelectedValue))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SelectedValue)
    }     
        <tr >
        <tbody>      
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

The next stage was to use an url alternate and i did create one - 
`~/Themes/XXXXXXXXX/Views/EditorTemplate-Dform-url-homepage.cshtml`

and copy pass the above code in the alternate file.

Refreshing the browser got me the following error:

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
        The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
         'IShapeProxy82be9d7cba51459e888e92b32898011b', but this dictionary requires a model item  of type 'Contrib.ChoiceList.ViewModels.ChoiceListFieldViewModel'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'IShapeProxy82be9d7cba51459e888e92b32898011b', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Contrib.ChoiceList.ViewModels.ChoiceListFieldViewModel'.

Source Error:


 Line 3:          @if (Model.Content != null) {
Line 4:              <div class="edit-item-content">
Line 5:                  @Display(Model.Content)
Line 6:              </div>
Line 7:          }


Source File: c:\00\01 projectos\xxxx\yyyyyyyy\NewWebSite.Orchard.Web\0\Orchard.Web.1.6\Orchard 0\Core\Contents\Views\Content.Edit.cshtml    Line: 5
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove the @model declaration at the top of the view as it is the dynamic shape template assigned to the Model, not the ViewModel you are expecting - see http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18195

You can access the view model through Model.Model e.g.

```
@{
    var myViewModel = 
        (Contrib.ChoiceList.ViewModels.ChoiceListFieldViewModel)Model.Model;
}
```

or access the dynamic fields directly

```
@Model.Model.Name
```